# C# Write XML File Containing Unknown Number of Nodes With the Same Name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Using C#, I'm trying to write an XML file that will contain an unknown number (unknown at compile time, I can figure out the number after I search the SQLite DB) of nodes (data being read from an SQLite DB) that will be named the same (Setting). The number of Setting nodes potentially can be in the thousands.

```
<Set>
  <Setting Name="Ted" empID="60000004">Ted</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Bill" empID="60000007">Bill</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Steve empID="60000010">Steve</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Sara" empID="60000013">Sara</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Tom" empID="60000016">Tom</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Sam" empID="60000019">Sam</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Alex" empID="60000022">Alex</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Sue" empID="60000025">Sue</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Jill" empID="60000028">Jill</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Mya" empID="60000031">Mya</Setting>
</Set>
```

Here is my code that I'm using, but failing:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Set"));

while (reader.Read())
{
    doc.Element("Set").Add(new XElement("Setting", _Name));
    doc.Element("Set").Element("Setting").Add(new XAttribute("empID", _ID));
}

doc.Save(_sOutputFolderName + "Employee_Information.xml");
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It's telling me that Setting already exists after the first loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to add the XAttribute to the same XElement on each loop.  Should be something like:

```
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Set"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var _Name = "n" + i ;
        var _ID = "12" + i;
        var setting = new XElement("Setting", _Name );
        setting.Add(new XAttribute("empID", _ID));
        doc.Element("Set").Add(setting);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Wouldn't that just give me n1, n2, n3, etc? I need the nodes to be the same name (Setting).

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Set"));

while (reader.Read()) {
    var setting = new XElement("Setting", "the name"); 
    setting.Add(new XAttribute("empID", "the id"));
    doc.Root.Add(setting);
}
```